# Undefined index: nickname after logout

Tags: php, session, logout

Login is working but when i am logout and i go on this page with this code  i have this problem:     Undefined index: nickname

```
 <?php
                $nickname = $_SESSION['nickname'];
                 if (isset($_SESSION['nickname'])){
                    echo'Vítej '. $nickname .'.<br>
                    <a href="logout.php">Odhlásit se</a>';
                } else {
                    echo'Tato stránka je přístupná pouze přihlášeným uživatelům. Pokud nemáš účet, <a href="/registrace.php">zaregistruj se</a>!<br>
                }
                ?>

My logout

<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: put `$nickname = $_SESSION['nickname'];` inside that `if`

Comment: session_start() required  on log out

Answer (score 0):

When there is no session, you cannot assign it to a variable. So the assigning should happen inside the if statements.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['nickname'])){
        $nickname = $_SESSION['nickname'];
        echo'Vítej '. $nickname .'.<br>
        <a href="logout.php">Odhlásit se</a>';
    } else {
        echo'Tato stránka je přístupná pouze přihlášeným uživatelům. Pokud nemáš účet, <a href="/registrace.php">zaregistruj se</a>!<br>
    }
?>
```